# Rust: How to initialise a value in one conditional branch for use in another?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I want to do something similar to the following pseudo Rust code:

```rust
let mut var;

for i in iter  {
  if condition  {
    var = some_obj;
  }
  else  {
    var.some_method();
  }
}
```

The obvious problem is that `var.some_method();` may run before `var` has been initialized in the true branch, and so this code won't compile.

I have a use case however where I know for sure that the false branch won't execute until the true branch has at least once. I'd like to be able to define `var` based on the results computed in the true branch, and then use it in the false branch on future loop iterations.

My only idea is to initialize `var` with a dummy variable outside of the loop, but this seems quite hacky. Is there a clean way to achieve what I want here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make var have type `Option<T>` and since you are sure var has been set when the else block is executed you can call `var.unwrap().some_method`. When you are going to set var it should be `var = Some(some_obj);`.

There also might be some way to do this using `MaybeUninnit` and/or using unsafe code, but you should only do that if you're (really) comfortable with rust

Comment: Also for your future sanity, I recommend to document the hell out of this loop so it's clear why you're confident that the unwrap is safe.